# Newly introduced ViewBinding won't work. Any idea why?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Just updated my Android studio to 3.6 version. There are news that `ViewBinding` is introduced and `findViewById` is no longer needed as long as you do not need it explicitly.

Used the developer.android [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable&utm_source=android-studio-3-6#java) to read the details, tried it as the websites says but so far to no avail.

`ResultProfileBinding` is not recognized by the system. What should I do? Any other early birds that are using this?

Comment: Rebuild project and try again, it may help you

Comment: Well, actually it did not help. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your name of layout

> For example, given a layout file called result_profile.xml:
>   The generated binding class is called ResultProfileBinding

If I have layout R.layout.activity_login the correct type is "ActivityLoginBinding"

Answer (score 0):

Today I have upgraded to studio 3.6 and the same issue has broken my brain. My solution is to upgrade to studio 4.0 beta 1, ViewBinding is working fine there.